# Datagridview include image in table column

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

enter image description hereI'm very new to visual studios so apologies if this has already been answered elsewhere as i have done several searches and can't find anything to fix my issue.

I currently have a datagridview within a form that is blank, and is populated when a user inserts data into textboxes,Combobox and a datetimepicker using the following code:

```
Public Class Add_Row_To_Datagridview_Using_Textboxes
Dim table As New DataTable("table")
Private Sub Add_Row_To_Datagridview_Using_Textboxes_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' header for 
    table.Columns.Add("Id", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    table.Columns.Add("First Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("Last Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("Age", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    table.Columns.Add("Gender", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("Date/Time", Type.GetType("System.String"))
```

Once the user pushes the button it generates into the datagridview using the following code;

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    table.Rows.Add(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text, ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), DateTimePicker1.Text)
```

This data is the exported with another button to excel for other purposes.

I'm basically trying to add a image into this datagridview at the end and i have found a code but i can to generate a column in advance which clashes with the already populated data which i have shown below due to when i click 'start' it already shows a column called images based on '   dgvImageColumn.HeaderText = "Image"'shown below.

```
   Private Sub Add_Row_To_Datagridview_Using_Textboxes_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' header for 
    table.Columns.Add("Id", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    table.Columns.Add("First Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("Last Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("Age", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    table.Columns.Add("Gender", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("Date/Time", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    '  Create Datagridview image column
    Dim dgvImageColumn As New DataGridViewImageColumn
    ' set header text to the column
    dgvImageColumn.HeaderText = "Image"
    dgvImageColumn.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvImageColumn)

    DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
    DataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 120
    DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
End Sub
```

Any advice how to simplify this so i can add another column at the end of "date/time" along with all the data inserted by the user in the textboxes, combobox and dataatimepicker to show a image which the user uploads with the as well as this is the current code i have;

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim opf As New OpenFileDialog
    opf.Filter = "Choose Image(*.jpg;*.png;*.gif)|*.jpg;*.png;*.gif"

    If opf.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(opf.FileName)
    End If
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for reading through this thread.

Ultimately i'm looking for a way to add an image using 'table.Columns.Add'to avoid the conflict.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUFss.png)

Comment: You might want to add a column that has a button saying 'Upload Image', on the click of which the user uploads the image, on completion of which the image is displayed. 
Also, you might want to edit the wording of your question to make your requirement more explicit and clear.

Comment: You'll have to excuse me as i'm very new to programming.

Comment: Okay. Take a screenshot of your datagridview, blank out any confidential information, and then put it up so people can see the problem you face. In general, if you expect a user to upload an image, you put an icon or a button that says 'upload' and then write some code behind the button, that asks for a path, then when path is given, runs more code to upload it, and more code (may be Ajax) to show it back to the user on the datagridview.

Comment: Image added to thread

Comment: Do you mean : The code you have currently works fine for you in terms of functionality, but you are looking forward for simpler code ?  Or you see a problem with the DataGridView display ? Do you wish that the image column be placed after the end of date/time column instead of in the beginning ? If yes, say, in your question, 'I want the image column to appear last in the datagridview'. 
Also, you could add the other columns using DataGridview1.columns.add instead of table.columns.add giving you more control and uniformity ?

Comment: Hi Whirlmind. The problem is that wheni 'start' the project the datagridview displays the image column automatically based on the above code to insert a column. On the other hand the other columns won't display until i have inserted information in the textbox's and clicked the button 'add'. I basically want to make it so when i 'upload' and image it won't display any data until i have clicked the button 'add'

Comment: Then shift the datagridview building code on click of the Add button instead of page load ?

Comment: when i add PictureBox1.Image to table.row.add and click add it shows the following in the column: System.Drawing.Bitmap

Answer (score 0):

Answered!

Load:

```
  Private Sub Add_Row_To_Datagridview_Using_Textboxes_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' header for 
    table.Columns.Add("Id", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    table.Columns.Add("First Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("Last Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("Age", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    table.Columns.Add("Gender", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("Date/Time", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("Image", GetType(Image))
```

Button:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    table.Rows.Add(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text, ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), DateTimePicker1.Text, PictureBox1.Image)
    DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
    DataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 120
    DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
    DataGridView1.DataSource = table
```

Thanks for the support!